# Change color of some posterior distributions while using mcmc_areas() from the R package bayesplot

Tags: r

I am using the ***mcmc_areas()*** function from 'bayesplot' in R to plot posterior distributions. I'd like to change the color/shade of a few specific variables in my plot, but not the rest. I'm hoping there is a way to do it with an added call associating a specific color with a specific parameter posterior. Or, maybe there is a way to color each posterior according to a grouping factor for the parameters. Referencing the plot from the vignette, say I wanted only the cyl posterior distribution in blue, and the rest still red. [example plot from vignette, all red color scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ2yI.png) Any suggestions? (Note: I know how to change the entire color scheme, I'm hoping to have more than one color in the same plot.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** I added the 'rhat' call as described in a vignette example. I assigned fake r-hat values to each of my predictor variables of `1, 1.1, 1.3` according to category (I have 3 categories) and the call + legend_move("none"). It works well enough for now. Per the recommendation of jgabry in GitHub, I'll give the package `ggdist` a look in the near future so that that I can make a cleaner plot with a legend when the time comes.